# EmbedFacebook posts height

Tags: html, css, facebook, post, embed

i have 4 embed facebook posts next to each other , and i am trying to set them to same height to get a better design .

i am using angular2 with ngx-facebook , this is how i place the html code

```
   <fb-post *ngIf="card.type=='post'" class="fb-post fb_iframe_widget" 
      [(attr.data-href)]="card.url" data-width="auto" data-height="700px" style="width:100%;">
      </fb-post>
```

but its not working , i get some of the posts equal height and some not check this image [Embed Posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQnZa.jpg)

any idea how to set them equal ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <fb-post *ngIf="card.type=='post'" class="fb-post fb_iframe_widget" 
      [(attr.data-href)]="card.url" data-width="auto" data-height="700px" style="width:100%; height: 200px; ">
      </fb-post>
```

**Give specific height in style attribute.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but this did not work or affect anything